# Delete a Sharepoint Wiki page that has no menu

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, wiki

Hi I created a Wiki in Sharepoint 2007, and then deleted the Home page.  Now when I go to the AllPages.aspx (ie the root of the wiki) I've got no menu options.  I cannot delete the Wiki page, or add any pages to it.

Here's what I see - there's no way to delete it as far as I can tell.  Any help greatly appreciated, don't want to start using Sharepoint if the first thing it does it create undeletable orphans...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to remember the menu options off the top of my head here, but you want to view all content and get to the pages library - in there you will see the wiki page and can delete it.

**EDIT**

Site Actions -> All Site Content -> Pages (doc library) -> Select Delete from the drop down list for the page name in question.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was on the right lines, though was in fact:
 in Site Actions - Site Settings - Site Administration (Site Libraries and Lists) - Customize "Test Page" - Permissions and Management (Delete this document library).  

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use stsadm to delete the site. Or delete SiteCollection in central administration.

Comment: It's a pretty extreme measure to delete a site collection when a single item in a single list gets messed up, isn't it?